# Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus in double integral

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, multiple-integral

How would one go about calculating
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int^t_{-t}f(z,t)dt.$$
And more specifically,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int^t_{-t}\int^t_{-t}f(x,y)dxdy$$
Assuming the necessary conditions, i got to
$$lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_{(-t-h,t+h)\setminus(-t,t)}f(x,y)}{h}+\int^t_{-t}\frac{d}{dt}(\int^t_{-t}f(x,y)dx)dy$$
Is this correct? And if it is, what would be necesary for the first term to go to $0$.

Comment: Quick approach:  Let $F(z,t) = \int_0^t f(z,x) dx$.  Then $$ \int_{-t}^t f(z,x) dx = F(z,t)- F(z,-t).$$
Now differentiate with respect to $t$.  You can let $z$ be a function of $t$ if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Define $G(a,b,c,d)$ by

$$ G(a,b,c,d) = \int_{c}^{d} \int_{a}^{b} f(x, y) \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y. $$

Assuming that $f$ is continuous near the rectangle $[a, b] \times [c, d]$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial a}
&= -\int_{c}^{d} f(a, y) \, \mathrm{d}y, &
\frac{\partial G}{\partial b}
&= \int_{c}^{d} f(b, y) \, \mathrm{d}y, \\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial c}
&= - \int_{a}^{b} f(x, c) \, \mathrm{d}x, &
\frac{\partial G}{\partial d}
&= \int_{a}^{b} f(x, d) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

So, if $F(t)$ denotes OP's integral, then

$$ F(t) := \int_{-t}^{t} \int_{-t}^{t} f(x, y) \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = G(-t, t, -t, t) $$

and hence we can compute its derivative by invoking the chain rule:

\begin{align*}
F'(t)
&= - \frac{\partial G}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial b} - \frac{\partial G}{\partial c} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial d} \biggr|_{(a,b,c,d)=(-t,t,-t,t)} \\
&= \int_{-t}^{t} [f(x, t) + f(x, -t)] \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{-t}^{t} [f(t, y) + f(-t, y)] \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{*}
\end{align*}

This also has an intuitive explanation. If $0 < t < s$, then $F(s) - F(t)$ is equal to the integral of $f(x, y)$ on the rectangular annulus

\begin{align*}
[-s, s]^2 \setminus (-t, t)^2
&= \underbrace{([-s, -t] \times [-s, s])}_{\text{left side}}
\cup \underbrace{([t, s] \times [-s, s])}_{\text{right side}}
\cup \underbrace{([-s, s] \times [-s, -t])}_{\text{bottom side}}
\cup \underbrace{([-s, s] \times [t, s])}_{\text{top side}} .
\end{align*}

Letting $ s = t + \Delta t$ and assuming $\Delta t$ is small, the integral of $f$ over the above annulus will be approximately $\Delta t$ times the line integral of $f$ along the boundary of $[-t, t]^2$, which is in accordance with the result $\text{(*)}$.

Comment: Would you say that in the general case with k varuables it would be the sum of k of these terms?

Comment: @user670565 In general we have $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_{[-t,t]^n} f=\int_{\partial[-t,t]^n} f. $$